# how to refresh a page after receiving webhook from stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using stripe for creating payments. After the payment is done user is redirected to payment status page. Payment status page is supposed show the latest plan user has subscribed for. Problem is I get the webhook from stripe after sometime which updates the user plan table. but user is redirected to user plan page immediately after the payment.

How can i show updated status after user is redirected.
Is there any way to halt the redirect till webhook request is complete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need on your end to wait for the webhook event to arrive before updating your customer here. Stripe API calls are synchronous which means that when you [create](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge) a charge you either get an [error](https://stripe.com/docs/api#errors) back which indicates the payment failed or a [charge object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object) back which indicates that the payment succeeded. Depending on those you can update your customer immediately without having to wait for the event to reach you.

The same logic applies for a new subscription here so when you [create](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_subscription) one you get a [subscription object](https://stripe.com/docs/api#subscription_object) back indicating it was successful and you can update your database immediately before redirecting the customer.

Most events should be seen as a way to verify the information you already have on your end and make sure your data is up to date and not validate a charge and update your customer directly.

Comment: But the problem I'm facing is with Retry Invoice.  in the returned invoice the subscription status is still "incomplete" . but in webhook 'payment.succedded" event the subscription object status is "active". so how can we refresh the user page at this situation? any suggestion?